# C# calculator adding two numbers after clearing the textview

Tags: c#, android

I'm trying to make a calculator in c# but the problem  is this, when a calculation is completed e.g 3 + 3= 6  the  user clicks the cancel button to begin a new one. But I noticed that I get wrong answers after using the cancel button, for e.g after clearing the first equation, 2+2 gives me 8 instead of 4. I really need help, this is my line of codes for num1 , plus, equalto and cancel buttons.

```
Button1.click += delegates { Textview.text += button1.text; }
Cancel.click += delegates { Textview.text = ""; }

Plus.click +=  { 
    Total1 += double.parse(textview.text);
    Text view.text = "";
}

Equalto.click += delegates {
    Total2 = total1 + double.parse(textview.text);
    Textview.text= total2.Tostring;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Cancel.click` set `total1=0` and `total2=0`